# Activity error with ActivityInjector get life cycle exception

Tags: android, android-activity

My app crashed on launch, then I got this error, this occurs rarely.

```java
[ 11-22 11:27:13.287 26135:26135 E/ActivityInjector ]
get life cycle exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
    at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(ActivityInjector.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:2032)
    at com.myapp.MyActivity.onResume(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1457)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4601)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4643)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3500(ActivityThread.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

I am using a Xiaomi device with Android 11, MIUI 12.5
This seems to be a system error, is there any way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Also happens to me with Android 11 on Xiaomi Redmi Note 11S.

Comment: @JithishPN it's a system error... I didn't find any solution, but they fixed it by surround with a `try-catch` block (**certain version of MIUI 13 Nightly, CN**). (error from `/system/framework/miui-framework.jar ActivityInjector#checkAccessControl`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't crash by this exception but I got this exception when my phone in light mode when I use this code

> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)

then I set up like this in activity of fragment (It's up to you)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(createBinding().root)
    initView()
}
```

Then exception gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the **values/themes/theme.xml**  file
2. Place a new *item* :

   `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`
3. Accept to override in values-v29 as de IDE sugests.
4. Try again.

*Happens in Xiaomi devices*

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've added this theme attribute. I decompiled `/system/framework/miui-framework.jar`(on MIUI 13) and found they've added a `try-catch` block so it doesn't crash anymore. So I'm not sure that's the reason.

Comment: @Laynier still have issue.. phone poco x3 android 11

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with Xiaomi phone models.

I think in your code super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) is called before the theme setting code. Therefore, when the app is launched, the basic activity operations start before the day/night mode is still set. This means that some operations that happen before the setDefaultNightMode operation can affect the operation of the app and thus lead to error messages.

In your new code, if super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) is called after the day/night mode settings have been checked using AppDelegate. This ensures that the night/day mode setting is done correctly before the underlying activity operations, so that possible mismatches or errors can be avoided.

So basically, calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) after setting the day/night mode allows you to follow a proper sequence and avoid errors.